# found xmin 2965836007 from before relfrozenxid 1749

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, vacuum

Autovacuum is not working on our AWS RDS PostgreSQL server from past few days. We run a manual vacuum to check the issue but we are getting below error for every database.

```
vacuumdb: vacuuming of database "databasename" failed: ERROR:  found xmin 2965836007 from before relfrozenxid 1749
```

On further analysis we found that below 2 system tables causing vacuum to terminate
pg_catalog.pg_authid
pg_catalog.pg_database

we are getting similar type of error for both the tables
*pg_authid*

```
found xmin 2965836007 from before relfrozenxid 1749
```

*pg_database*

```
found xmin 3535916373 from before relfrozenxid 1749
```

vacuum analyze is working fine for all tables except these two.
PostgreSQL version is 9.6.9 and autovacuum settings are default RDS settings.

We have gone through various threads but didn't get any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is usually caused by an old software bug in PostgreSQL. Try to `pg_dump` the database and restore it to a new cluster.

Comment: Do you have any update on this @yogi ?